# drawArc() rendering is inconsistent when the arc length changes

Tags: java, swing

I need to draw an arc around a volume knob, the arc length represents the volume.

I tried with Graphics.drawArc() and Arc2D.Double, but the result is not good: the path of the arc is not exactly the same for different extent values.

[image]

```
public class ArcComponent extends JComponent
{

    private ImageIcon knobImage = new ImageIcon(ArcComponent.class.getResource("Knob-w37.png"));

    int arcLength = 220;        // Degrees

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // Paint knob image
        knobImage.paintIcon(this, g2, 20, 20);

        // Add arc
        var arc = new Arc2D.Double(22, 22, 32, 32, 220 - arcLength, arcLength, Arc2D.OPEN);
        g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g2.draw(arc);

        g2.dispose();
    }

    void shorter()
    {
        arcLength -= 5;
        if (arcLength < 0)
        {
            arcLength = 260;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    void longer()
    {
        arcLength += 5;
        if (arcLength > 260)
        {
            arcLength = 0;
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

How could I ensure that the path of the arc is always the same?

EDIT: added knob image painting

[image]

Comment: *EDIT: there is one more constraint* - post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I updated the code and the gif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dirty trick: draw the complete circle and ovewrite the part that you don't need with a shape, same color of background.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    Shape circle=new Ellipse2D.Double(20, 20, 30, 30);
    g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
    g2.draw(circle);
    Shape arc=new Arc2D.Double(10,10,50,50,230,360-arcLength,Arc2D.PIE);
    g2.setColor(getBackground());
    g2.fill(arc);
    g2.dispose();
}
```

Unfortunately this requires the arc to be drawn before any other thing in the same area, but you can probably deal with this.

EDIT: For the additional constraint, the inconsistent rendering is actually due to the stroke, so try creating a thick shape and fill it, example:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    double thickness=8.0; //This replaces your stroke width
    
    GeneralPath shape=new GeneralPath();
    
    shape.append(new Arc2D.Double(20-thickness/2,20-thickness/2, 30+thickness, 30+thickness, 230, -arcLength, Arc2D.OPEN),false);
    shape.append(new Arc2D.Double(20+thickness/2,20+thickness/2, 30-thickness, 30-thickness, 230-arcLength, arcLength, Arc2D.OPEN),true);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g2.fill(shape);
    g2.dispose();
}
```

Comment: This works but I can't use this method because in the real app the paintComponent() draws over a knob image behind. I'll update the question.

Comment: @jjazzboss Ok, I updated the solution with a new proposal

Answer (score 0):

Simply draw a full circle and clip on the arc shape (with some padding to ensure everything gets drawn).

```java
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(20, 20, 30, 30);
int d = 2;
Arc2D arc = new Arc2D.Double(20 - d, 20 - d, 30 + 2 * d, 30 + 2 * d, 230, -arcLength, Arc2D.PIE);

g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
g2.setClip(arc);
g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
g2.draw(circle);

knobImage.paintIcon(this, g, 20, 20);
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention an additional constraint, I just edited the question.

Comment: Just paint the knob with the parent Graphics object as it doesn't have the clip set.

Comment: I think you mixed arc and circle. I tested it, it does not work, knobImage overwrites the arc. Thanks anyway.